# Import/restore backed up sqlite from iphone app

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, import

I am working on developing my first iPhone app using Core Data. Currently puzzled with how to restore previously backed up sqlite file.

I have been successful in exporting the sqlite file via email. But can't figure out how to implement the import/restore feature. Basically this is what I wish to accomplish as user clicks on "Import Data"

1. Display a view listing URL that      user can access via any computer       (keeping the app running)
2. When user accesses the URL, a    simple web page with two    buttons    (Browse, Upload) appears
     2a. User can browse and get the sqlite file from local machine and hit upload
3. As app is done receiving the file,
     3a. Runs logic of converting NSData to sqlite and saves it in      documents folder
     3b. Informs user that import is complete
4. Finally app has the restored    data..

I have been looking around through articles but am unable to find any helpful information.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am still struggling. Any tutorials that i can take help from? I assume this should not be as hard as I am finding it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way.

1. Download the archived/exported data to tmp folder
2. Close the current ManagedContext to the database
3. Rename the existing database to a temporary name.
4. Create a new database with code or copy a blank database from the bundle to the document directory.
5. Connect the ManagedContext to the new database.
6. Read the archived file and import data into database.
7. Once success, delete the archived data file and the old database file which is the temporary name.
8. If not success, rename the temporary database back to the current name.

Comment: All this is covered under (3.a). My struggle is how to accomplish step 1 & 2

Comment: How did you get it the server? I would use NSURLConnection to download the file.

Comment: I used MFMailComposeViewController to export it via email. I will try NSURLConnection for import and write the result. Thanks for the pointer.